# Unable To Pass Query Parameters As An Array To An External API

Tags: php, laravel, rest, laravel-8

I am following the documentation for a webinar platform to allow participants register through the API. The payload is to be delivered like this:

```
$params = array(
'registration' => array(
    1 => 'John',
    2 => 'Dee',
    3 => 'example@domain.com',
),
```

This is the screenshot of the documentation for just adding a participant:

[image]

Below is the code I wrote:

```
$client = new Client();

    $headers = [
        'X-Api-Key' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    ];

    $params = [
        'registration' => [
            1 => 'Justice',
            2 => 'Arthur',
            3 => 'jarthur@gmail.com',
        ],
    ];

    $response = $client->post('https://api.clickmeeting.com/v1/conferences/7436564/registration', [
        'headers' => $headers,
        'json' => $params,
    ]);

    $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();

    // log the response
    Log::debug('ClickMeeting API response', [
        'status' => $response->getStatusCode(),
        'body' => $body,
    ]);

    // handle response as needed

}
```

However all tries have not been successful. I keep getting this error:

```
[![ "code": 422,
"name": "VALIDATION_ERRORS",
"errors": [
    {
        "name": 1,
        "message": "The \"Name\" field is required and can`t be empty."
    },
    {
        "name": 3,
        "message": "The \"Email Address\" field is required and can`t be empty."
    }
]]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am using Laravel 8

Comment: Is there a doc about the `Client::post()` parameters? They might be wrong, as we don't know what kind of HTTP client you are using. I currently found this: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#request-data

Comment: It looks like [Guzzlehttp/Client](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle). Laravel's HTTP client is just a simple wrapper around Guzzle, for better testing.

Comment: weird that fail on 1 and 3, but second name is ok..

Comment: Yeah. I told them their documentation was too bleak. OMG

Comment: Try 0,1,2 as keys. That would explain the name missing and the email being invalid.

Comment: @JamesDonohue did the key replace worked?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a **similar issue** with the [ClickMeeting API](https://dev.clickmeeting.com/api-doc/#post_registration), particularly when trying to submit registrations that included **custom fields**. I had one "Phone Number" field added via the ClickMeeting UI. As [@James Donohue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20809908/james-donohue) already said the API documentation provides details for only three parameters, and there's a noticeable gap concerning how to manage custom fields that are added on the registration page.

When attempting to register a new attendee with additional fields on the registration form, I received a **validation error** similar to the following:

```json
  "code":422,
  "name":"VALIDATION_ERRORS",
  "errors":[
    {
      "name":2221582,
      "message":"The \"Phone Number\" field is required and can`t be empty."
    }
  ]
}
```

Right now I believe that the ClickMeeting API, as per my understanding, **does not natively support custom fields** in the registration process via API.

At least we don't know how to pass these custom fields, in order not to receive an error response. I also tried to pass the field names as keys in the $params array and so on, but no luck.

## Fortunately...

After some trial & error, I discovered that the API can handle the $params array with a specific set of fields in a predefined order. These fields and their order seem to be fixed, and custom fields are not directly supported. However, the predefined fields coincidentally included a slot for a "Phone" field, which suited my needs.

Here's how you can structure the $params array with some additional fields:

```php
$params = [
    'registration' => [
        1 => 'First name',
        2 => 'Last name',
        3 => 'email@example.com',
        4 => 'Address',
        5 => 'City',
        6 => 'State/Province',
        7 => 'Zip/Postal Code',
        8 => 'Country',
        9 => 'Phone',
        10 => 'Company',
    ],
];
```

For those facing similar issues with the ClickMeeting API, it's important to understand that the API as per my findings currently doesn't seem to support custom fields. Only a specific set of parameters in a specific order can be passed.

Hope that helps!